# pyodbc with msaccess: too few parameters. Trying to set date to yesterday in a column

Tags: python, ms-access, pyodbc

```
import pyodbc
conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=C:\testing\mydb.accdb')
crs = conn.cursor()
crs.execute('UPDATE [testtable] SET "dateoflastchange" = DATEADD("d", -1, DATE())')
# Too few parameters. Expected 1
```

I tried replacing DATEADD with DateAdd and replacing commas with semi-colons. Also "day" instead of "d" as seen in other examples. I cannot figure it out. In the past it was usually some Microsoft syntax that I had wrong. Where did he expect 1 parameter but got 0?

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

```
crs.execute("UPDATE [testtable] SET [dateoflastchange] = DATEADD('d', -1, DATE())")
```

I had to use brackets as mentioned by Gustav **and** swap the quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Try with Access SQL syntax:

```
crs.execute('UPDATE [testtable] SET [dateoflastchange] = DATEADD("d", -1, DATE())')
```

Comment: Hm thank you, I didn't try that yet - but it leads to the same error :/

Comment: Ahhh I got it!! I need `"` outside and `'` inside! In the past I had other problems which were solved by unexpected solutions like this. At least to me this is unexpected. I got this idea from another search, where somebody talked about the quotes.